# Excel formula / VBA to find closest value in unsorted random sheet

Tags: excel, vba, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to pull the closest value to the one I'm entering into the Excel file.  That's my exemplary table, containing text in random places:

```
LE  893 337
574 CH  185
524 768 IA
```

(example: if D4=1, return 185)

At the beginning, I was using `=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A3-$D$4)),ABS(A1:A3-$D$4),0))` to find the closest value in A column, to the one in D4 cell, and then comparing all the results to the D4 cell again, but the moment any text appeared it started showing #VALUE error. No implications of ISTEXT or ISNUMBER really helped, just started throwing empty cell instead of #VALUE error.

Also, I can't believe that it really is the best solution existing to do that. I obviously could write a macro creating new sheet, copying all the numbers into it, then comparing every single column, and then comparing every result, but that sound so silly and resource consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AGGRAGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$1:$C$3/(ABS(A1:C3-D4) = AGGREGATE(15,6,ABS($A$1:$C$3-D4),1)),1)
```

[image]